# R error in a loop simulating multiple graphs

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, classification, roc

I'm trying to construct a loop to plot 10 ROCs and to store AUC scores for 10 models by using R library `ROCR`. The loop I have created generates an error:

> Error in prediction(as.numeric(var_name[i]), s_test$clickthrough) : 
>      Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for 
>      each run.

When I tried to run prediction individually there is nothing wrong with number of labels not equal to predictions. Could anyone help me to fix the error caused by the for loop?

Individual prediction (this works fine):

```
lr.pred<- prediction(as.numeric(lda_predp),
                  s_test$clickthrough)
AUC1 <- performance(lr.pred,"auc")@y.values[[1]]
lr.ROC1 <- performance(lr.pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(lr.ROC1, main= "LDA")
```

Problem occurs in the loop:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,5))

var_name = c("nb_predp","lda_predp","qda_predp","lg_prob","lda_forwardp","lda_lassop",
         "lda_pred_int_p","lda_pred_t_p","lda_pred_v_p","lda_pred_c_p")


    for (i in 1:length(var_name)){

      lr.pred[i] <- prediction(as.numeric(var_name[i]),
                  s_test$clickthrough)

      AUC[i] <- performance(lr.pred[i],"auc")@y.values[[1]]
      lr.ROC[i] <- performance(lr.pred[i],"tpr","fpr")
      plot(lr.ROC[i], main= var_name[i])

    }
```

I checked the format of lr.pred, it turns out it is not a vector but rather a prediction class created by ROCR package. I think that could be the problem, but does anyone know how to extract the data from ROCR package to fit for graphs?

**Revised**
lr.pred will be a "prediction" object and lr.ROC will be a "performance" object with a specific class.

```
 lr.pred = list()

 var_name = 
 c("nb_predp","lda_predp","qda_predp","lg_prob","lda_forwardp","lda_lassop", 
  "lda_pred_int_p","lda_pred_t_p","lda_pred_v_p","lda_pred_c_p")

 for (i in 1:length(var_name)){
 lr.pred[[i]] <- prediction(var_name[i], s_test$clickthrough)

 AUC[i] <- performance(lr.pred[i],"auc")@y.values[[1]]
 lr.ROC[i] <- performance(lr.pred[i],"tpr","fpr") 
 plot(lr.ROC[i], main= var_name[i])

}
```

Comment: Please show the the successful individual (non-loop) code. Also, the `@` seems out of place -maybe typo here?

Comment: @Parfait I think the class of lr.pred is not in vector, but rather information generated from ROCR package. Do you think there may be a way to extract the information needed from ROCR for the graphs?

Comment: Once again, please show the working individual (non-loop) code. I do not know that package  so I will try helping with your loop syntax.

Comment: @Parfait Hi I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string in `prediction()` call and not named object.

- In your working individual non-loop run you call: `prediction(as.numeric(lda_predp)...)`
- In your loop it is akin to passing a quoted string: 
  `prediction(as.numeric("lda_predp")...)`

To resolve, either assign *var_name* to named objects (i.e., no strings) and run `for` loop as is:

```
var_name = c(nb_pred1, lda_pred1, qda_pred1, lg_prob, lda_pred_1_p, lda_pred_2_p,
             lda_pred_int_p, lda_pred_t_p, lda_pred_v_p, lda_pred_c_p)
```

Or use `get()` inside loop to reference an environment object by string:

```
var_name = c("nb_pred1", "lda_pred1", "qda_pred1", "lg_prob", "lda_pred_1_p", "lda_pred_2_p",
             "lda_pred_int_p", "lda_pred_t_p", "lda_pred_v_p", "lda_pred_c_p")

lr.pred <- vector(); AUC <- vector(); lr.ROC <- vector()

for (i in 1:length(var_name)){
     lr.pred[i] <- prediction(as.numeric(get(varname[i]), s_test$clickthrough)
     ...
}
```

But likely, you want to run the latter since you assign *main* to a string: `main=var_name[i]`.

Comment: After I used get(), another error message appears  "Error: object 'lr.pred' not found" . May have to do with prediction() format..

Comment: ida_predp = lda_pred1 . I changed the name but forgot to edit my post to reflect the change. I have updated the post. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: So does it work with correct names? Again, check if those objects exist in environment.

Comment: no, the loop still generate the same error after name change and get(). I think it's prediction() from ROCR that is causing the problem. It doesn't generate a vector...

Comment: ida_predp does exist in my global environment as a large numeric with 122611 elements. The other objects are all present in global environment with the exact same property.

Comment: So is the error still same as your first comment above? Do you run an error with this answer?

Comment: You need to initialize the vectors, *lr.pred, AUC , lr.ROC*, prior to using them in `for` loop. Sorry, I thought you did so but did not post. See my edit.

Comment: I added a revision in the original post, and I believe lr.pred will be a "prediction" object and lr.ROC will be a "performance" object with a specific class. However I received the same error:  `Error in prediction(var_name[i], s_test$clickthrough) : 
  Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each run.` . All variables passed through have the same element numbers on global environment.

Comment: You are not using `get()` as advised with my answer: `var_name[i]` is a character string and not actual environment object.

Comment: Thank you for the patient guidance, I added get() and looked deeper into performance() and was able to fix the loop.